# ¿Como mostrar "Loading..." mientras carga un formulario?

Tags: php, jquery, datatables

Tengo una tabla con mas de 50mil registros y estoy mostrándolos en una tabla usando **DataTables**

¿Cómo puedo hacer para que mientras se cargan todos los registros en la tabla aparezca un mensaje de "Cargando..." o una imágen de carga?

Actualmente al momento de cargar mi pagina empieza a cargar toda la información y esto lleva un tiempo al tratarse de una gran cantidad de datos y una vez terminado el proceso, recién carga el `DataTables` como debe de verse y funcionar.

Código de mi tabla:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="dataTables-example">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Codigo</th>
                                    <th>Denominacion</th>
                                    <th>Unidad Medida</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <?php
                                foreach ($ArrayMaterial as $Material) {
                                    echo '<tr>';
                                    echo '<td>'.$Material->CodigoMaterial.'</td>';
                                    echo '<td>'.stripslashes(utf8_encode($Material->DenominacionMaterial)).'</td>';
                                    echo '<td>'.$Material->UnidadMedidaMaterial.'</td>';
                                    echo '</tr>';
                                }
                                ?>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
```

Código del **DataTable**:

```
<script>    
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#dataTables-example').dataTable();
    });
</script>
```

Gracias!

Comment: Deberias de agregar tu codigo para que sea mas facil reproducir una respuesta.

Comment: Ahora entiendo un poco mejor lo que te pasa, vos estas queriendo mostrar 50k de registros, que son muchisimos, en estos casos de querer mostrar tanta cantidad de datos lo que podes hacer es usar datatables pero con "server side processing", esto quiere decir que los datos son cargados a la tabla con llamadas ajax cuando correspondan, por ejemplo al cambiar de pagina o escribir algo en el campo de busqueda.
Te dejo un link donde podes encontrar mas informacion https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side